# Wordpress: Calendar Widget displaying posts by custom field (date)

Tags: wordpress, calendar, widget, custom-fields

I created a website build around a custom post type events. These events have custom fields, one of them is the event-date (the date the event is happening, NOT post publish date). I'd like a calendar widget that simply highlights the days an event is happening (maybe with a link to it). This means i need to plug my custom fields into a calendar widget plugin.

I found this post from 2 years ago, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-in-a-calendar-using-custom-field-as-date?replies=8 - it seems they wanted exactly what i'm asking for. Unfortunately i couldn't figure out how to do it with the plugin mentioned by them (FT calendar).

Most calendar widget plugins simply use the pust-publish date. I need them to take their date-data from a custom field.
Do you guys have an idea which calendar-widget-plugin/way would be best for me?

Answer (score 0):

After I've made a search and test of some of the event calendar plugins, calendar that would be closest to your need is [All-in-One Event Calendar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/). After installing it is necessary to upgrade to the Standard version. The plugin has far too many options than it is needed, but is highly configurable so it can be configured to work roughly what you need.

[Here](http://www.jimbowes.com/2011/01/web/wordpress-calendar-plugins/) is also the link with the analysis of different Wordpress event calendar plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up doing the calculations on the frontend (JavaScript)